# Why the conditional statement like "if regressor:" causes an error?

Tags: python, if-statement, scikit-learn

I have tested several kinds of regressors from scikit-learn.
But, when I use if-statement only with regressor, I faced the error case like the sample code below.

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor, HistGradientBoostingRegressor

for j, model in enumerate([MLPRegressor(), HistGradientBoostingRegressor(), GradientBoostingRegressor()]):
    if model:
        print(f'{j}: True. You defined the model: %s'%type(model))
```

---

```py
0: True. You defined the model: <class 'sklearn.neural_network._multilayer_perceptron.MLPRegressor'>
1: True. You defined the model: <class 'sklearn.ensemble._hist_gradient_boosting.gradient_boosting.HistGradientBoostingRegressor'>
AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingRegressor' object has no attribute 'estimators_'
```

---

Unlike the first two models, only the third model causes `AttributeError`. On the other hand, `if model is not None:` doesn't cause the error.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

When evaluating `if not <object>`, python interpreter checks `__nonzero__()` dunder method (if implemented), then a non-zero return value of `__len__()` (if implemented) and finally compares the object to `None`.

Depending by inheritance, there is some inconsistency regarding `__len__()` implementation in different sklearn model classes. It is a known issue (see e.g. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/23769, https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10487) yet as far as I know, it is not prioritized to be straightened out anytime soon.

Using `if <object> is (not) None` is a recommended workaround.

Comment: Good. Thanks. This is a little bit of a reason for the difference between models. However, I would like to know more specifically why there is no problem with MLPRegressor and HistGradientBoostingRegressor because I am developing some functions using those models together.

Comment: `MLPRegressor()` and `HistGradientBoostingRegressor()` are both based on `BaseEstimator()` (no `__len__()`). `GradientBoostingRegressor()` is based upon `BaseEnsemble()`, which has `__len__()` implemented (but working only when fitted).

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I improved my code referring to your answer. Thanks.